# SQL DATE and TIME to DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

I have date and time column in my table. I want to select all objects which has date and time larger than current time plus one hour:

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND time >= TIME(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 hour)
```

However this is logically not correct. If date is tomorrow and time is less than current HH:MM it will not select that record.
How can I use my date and time to compare with current datetime?
I am using php 5.2 with mysql

Comment: Any reason why you can't use a DATETIME column that combines both?

Comment: In all cases I want to display date and time separately and I group by date and I have already written lots of code, so it is a bit hard for me to change now.

Comment: You can display date and time separately with a DATETIME, and group by date - that wouldn't be a problem. (Just in case you're rewriting it at some point)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I recommend using a DATETIME column to make this filtering more efficent. However, this works if you cannot change:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (date = CURDATE() AND time >= TIME(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 hour))
OR date > CURDATE()
```

Comment: Small, possibly irrelevant caveat: this can produce incorrect results between 11pm and midnight

Answer (score 1):

You can split your condition into two conditions...

- When the date is equal to today and more than an hour ahead of the current time:

  `date == CURDATE() AND time >= TIME(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 hour)`
- When the date is greater than today:

  `date > CURDATE()`

...and chain them together using `OR` and parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (date == CURDATE() AND time >= TIME(NOW()+INTERVAL 1 hour)) OR date > CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

First check whether the date is today and if time is greater then current time. The second condition is to check whether the date is greater than current date. Because if the date is greater then current date then automatically it's time is ahead.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (date = CURDATE() AND time >= TIME(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 hour))
OR date > CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND time >= TIME(HOUR(NOW()) + 1);
```

or maybe just

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND time >= HOUR(NOW()) + 1;
```

Comment: This is wrong, you should use OR not AND. See alexn and ASGM correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @Pekka, all the answers posted so far will give the wrong answer between 11pm and midnight.  I don't work with MySQL, but I can look stuff up.  A better approach seems to be the timestamp() function.

[This reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) states:

```
With two arguments, it adds the time expression expr2 to the date 
or datetime expression expr1 and returns the result as a datetime value.
```

Why not use timestamp() with two arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
mytable 
WHERE 
CONCAT( date, " ", time ) > (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR );
```

Personally I suggest that you get rid of the separate fields for date and time and create a consolidated 'DATETIME' field. I also suggest adding an INDEX to that field.

That would make your queries better and faster. :)